# Using MYSQLI in seperate / distinct PHP functions

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm transitioning from MYSQL to MYSQLI and I am in need of assistance with putting MYSQLI into separate / distinct functions.

From all the "tutorials" i have located on the web, they all have everyrything in one big long code, and not distinct / separate functions that my main scripts can call.

Eg :-

- Connect to MYSQLI
- Do SELECT
- Exit MYSQLI

what i'm after is :-

## MYSQLI.PHP

```
     <?
     function connect_mysqli()
     {
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","wrong_user","my_password","my_db");
     // Check connection
     if (!$con)
     {
     die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
     }
     // Return the connection back to where i called it ??
     }
     function do_query ($sql)
     {
     $row = $con->query("$sql")->fetch_array();
     return $row;
     }
     function close_mysqli()
     {
      $mysqli->close();
     }
     ?>
```

in my script  i want to call :-

another.php

```
      <?
      include_once("MYSQLI.PHP");
       connect_mysqli();

         ....

        do some SELECT
       do some UPDATE

       close_mysqli();
        ?>
```

So far, from the error codes I am receiving, the "connection" to mysqli is not being passed to/from my other script(s)

Has anyone got a working / tested example of mysqli using functions (not just half the code) - but a working example of  simple  SELECT

Once i get that far, i can do the rest.

Comment: Have you looked at OOP? Is that something you are willing to consider as it would solve your issue nicely.

Comment: Your connection is actually not passed. Read about the variable scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fix your include file to

```
/**
 * @return mysqli
 */
function connect_mysqli()
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","wrong_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (!$con)
    {
        die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    return $con;
}

function do_query ($con, $sql)
{
    $row = $con->query("$sql");
    if($row) {
        return $row->fetch_array();
    }
    return null;
}

function close_mysqli($con)
{
    $con->close();
}
```

now you can run a script like this

```
include_once("MYSQLI.PHP");
$connection = connect_mysqli();

if(null !== $connection) {
    print_r(do_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM yourTable"));

    close_mysqli($connection);
}
```

but for correct handling create a connection interface and a implementation for mysqli like this

```
interface myConnectionClass {
    function connect();
    ....
}
```

and a mysqli implementation

```
class myMysqlIConnection implements myConnectionClass {
    function connect() {
       //do more... save connection etc...
       return true; //sucess
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Your answer works very good. Except i can't get a result with "if($row)" subroutine) - If I use the following code, it works fine :)  -  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     print_r($row);
  }

Answer (score 0):

[Example Demos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
Scroll down there are a lot of exmaples...

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

/* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
if ($mysqli->query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City") === TRUE) {
    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");
}

/* Select queries return a resultset */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10")) {
    printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* If we have to retrieve large amount of data we use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM City", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {

    /* Note, that we can't execute any functions which interact with the
       server until result set was closed. All calls will return an
       'out of sync' error */
    if (!$mysqli->query("SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: And why do I get -1 for googling that for him? I did the work he would be able to do on his own within 5 seconds.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: But it directly answers his question and would finish this topic so there is no need to create a comment.

Comment: It doesn't answer his question at all. All you do is spout what he can read. What he wants is a function he can call, that's not a function.

Comment: Well, it contains exactly what he demanded "Has anyone got a working / tested example of mysqli using functions (not just half the code) - but a working example of simple SELECT" - should I reinvent the wheel? When I write it out of my head it wont look much different you know...

Comment: Look at silly's answer, it's quite different and rather specific and not so lazy.

Comment: And he is not lazy or what? I am not the first guy in the line screaming about documentations but this one is clear a copyable example and not hard to find, really not.

Comment: Thanks styphon. yes it doesn't answer the query. (i've managed to log in.) . The above script example are all on ONE page / script. It is not in functions.  I do not want to write 20 PHP scripts for 20-tasks, and ALL have a MYSQLI connect script included. i just want ONE connect script, & 20+ php scripts able to use that connectipn as & when i want to..

Comment: @Steini I've been in the same situation as the OP a few years ago. When you're new and starting out it's annoying that people assume you haven't looked at the official documentation just because you don't understand it when you ask a simple question on SO. Don't assume he's lazy just because he asks for help on a simple question. The documentation you linked did not answer his question. That's why I gave you a -1.